# which GPIO pin is connected to the physical knob on the side of the lilygo T-Watch S3?

Tags: esp32

On the LilyGo T-Watch S3 2020, which GPIO pin is connected to the physical knob on the side of the watch?

I'm aware of the schematic [here](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/TTGO_TWatch_Library/blob/t-watch-s3/schematic/T_WATCH_S3.pdf) but I can't find the knob in that schematic. I have also scoured the pin definitions in C code [here](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/TTGO_TWatch_Library/blob/t-watch-s3/src/utilities.h#L116-L163) but I see no mention of the physical knob.

The knob I'm referring to is this one:

[image]